# Align text center on top of background

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css, sorry if this is a "repeat" I couldn't find an answer that worked for me, but maybe I have a seperate problem. I have set a background with this CSS code here:

```
.background {
position: fixed;
top: -50%;
left:-50%;  
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
}
.background img { 
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
margin: auto; 
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
}
```

And have used it in HTML here:

```
<div class="background"><img src="lol_background.png" alt="League Champion Background" /></div>
```

Now, I'm trying to center a title on top of this background, but for some reason I cannot figure it out, my CSS for the header is here:

```
#headtxt {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
z-index: 100;
color: pink; 
}
```

And I call it in the HTML like so:

```
<h1 id="headtxt">Before and After: League AP Item Changes</h1>
```

So, here is what I've tried: When I remove `position: absolute` the text falls behind the background. And obviously right now, having the `text-align: center;` seems to be doing nothing. So I'm not exactly sure what is going on, but I assume it's some lame rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of an element whose `position` property is set to `absolute`   is determined automatically. To center the text you have to set the width of `#headtext` to `100%`.

```css
.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left:-50%;  
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
.background img { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
#headtxt {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  color: pink; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature" />
</div>

<h1 id="headtxt">Before and After: League AP Item Changes</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background with html tag for your background of application. You do not need other divs to place background. Try the below code.

http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/ZGZxXK

Before and After: League AP Item Changes

```
<style>
html { 
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JcWrY8U.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#headtxt {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where would I put "lol_background.png" in this example to make it show up on my site (obviously it wont just show up in the test environment you provided)?

Comment: Basically, I just need to have "lol_background.png" instead of url(http://i.imgur.com/JcWrY8U.jpg), but I don't know how to implement that.